# How to read a xlsx worksheet file in tcl?

Tags: tcl

Currently, I am reading a file by converting it to CSV format. Is there any way we can read an excel worksheet by tcl?

Comment: The xlsx format is basically a bunch of zipped XML files. You can mount the xlsx file using zipfs and then process the files with tdom.

Comment: the easiest way is to use this package : [CAWT](http://www.cawt.tcl3d.org/download/CawtReference.html) or without Excel installed this package : [ooxml](https://tcl.sowaswie.de/repos/fossil/ooxml/home). If you have problems using CAWT I can give you an example

Comment: The easiest way is probably with ooxml, but the documentation is _very_ sparse on how to read things.

Comment: @mkn can you share a basic example which employs this package.Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below example with [CAWT](http://www.cawt.tcl3d.org/download/CawtReference.html) package to open a csv file and get its values:

```
package require cawt

# Open a new instance
set appId [Excel::OpenNew false] ; # set true to open an visible Excel
set workbookId [Excel::AddWorkbook $appId]

set csvfile {c:\temp\test.csv}
# 1;2;3
# 4;5;6

try {

    set worksheetId [Excel::GetWorksheetIdByIndex $workbookId 1] ; # open first sheet
    set rangeId [Excel::SelectRangeByString $worksheetId "A1"]   ; # select range 'A1'
    
    # Import csv file to range A1
    Excel::Import $rangeId $csvfile \
           -consecutive false \
           -delimiter ";" \
           -decimalseparator "."
    
    # Get last column & row used...
    set numCols [Excel::GetNumUsedColumns $worksheetId]
    set numRows [Excel::GetNumUsedRows $worksheetId]
    
    # Get values 
    puts [Excel::GetMatrixValues $worksheetId 1 1 $numRows $numCols]
    
} finally {
    
    # no need to close Excel if visible...
    if {![Excel::Visible $appId]} {
        Excel::Close $workbookId
        Excel::Quit $appId false
    } else {
        Cawt::Destroy ; # delete com object
    }
}
```

Result :

```
{1.0 2.0 3.0} {4.0 5.0 6.0}
```